# Bootstrap Media queries Orientation Change to Landscape not working under Physical Device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am facing one very strange issue in bootstrap, basically I have this page http://excellencewebworks.com/bootstrap/video_skin.html

Here I am adding video covered with a tablet video skin. When I check the page under responsive mode in `Mozilla Firefox -> Tools-> Responsive Design View for 360 x 640 dimension` it works good under portrait and landscape mode.

But when checking the same page in physical device, it works only in portrait and not landscape, design gets altered in landscape mode. Strange to see this.

Can anyone please look into this and let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Comment: you may try removing `only` from media queries.

Comment: Not working though after removing only!

Comment: Try this  : [iphone 4 and 4s](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/#iphone-queries)

Comment: I don't need to test on iphone4 and 4s I just want it work on 360 * 640 dimension device, Later on I will make for iphones and ipads as well but I am just testing for this one dimension Once I am sure then I can make rest one.

Comment: The problem is its working good under emulator then it should work on device also but in device not working under landscape mode!

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for landscape and portrait mode media queries try this.

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

Comment: Above media queries makes no sense, as of now I just want to get it work on 360 * 640 device.

Comment: you can add which resolution you want instead of specific values in example i given.

Comment: You can also check my media queries written @media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 640px) { }

Comment: When I check ion mobile only working in portrait but landscape mode css not working properly!! but works fine when I check in emulator

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Give it a try something like this :

```
@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px){
   /*-----style----*/
}
```

Also make sure your media queries are not overlapping.

Comment: sorry bro! Not working @media screen and (min-width : 360px) and (max-width : 640px) {} makes no effect.